# Unity5 - Make a server only for multiplayer game

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I followed the Unity tutorial of an online multiplayer game ([here](https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking)), and the architecture is the following : 
[image: Client + Server architecture]

But I would like to have this architecture :

[image: Server only architecture]

I would like to really separate the client part and the server part in an online game. I'm new with Unity and especially with online multiplayer game and I really don't know how to do that. I don't want the solution, but maybe idea of how to do that.

Thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: The simple way is to keep as you have it, but the 'master' client doesn't accept any player input (nor has any player specific elements e.g. character, gun etc).

Comment: so for example with a`if (Network.isServer)` test, I desable all the controler ?

Comment: Correct.  15chars.

Comment: Thanks! I will try with that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I am surprised you didn't learn the Tut and post this question. obviously you can make separate server.*

As unity [**UNet basic concept**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetConcepts.html) stated:

> In the unity networking system, games have a Server and multiple
>   Clients. **When there is no dedicated server, one of the clients plays**
>   **the role of the server - we call this client the “host”**

**Three Modes of UNet Multiplayer Game:**

A Networking multiplayer game can run in ***three modes*** - as a **client**, as a **dedicated server**, or as a “**Host**” which is both a client and a server at the same time. Networking is designed to make the same game code and assets work in all of these cases. Developing for the single player version of the game and the multiplayer version of the game should be the same thing.

NetworkManager has funcions for entering each of these modes:

```
NetworkManager.StartClient()
NetworkManager.StartServer()
NetworkManager.StartHost()
```

[**Check UNetManager for more details**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can open a Unity instance as a dedicate server.

`NetworkManager.StartServer();`

However for current state of UNET you can only have 1 room per Unity instances.

Which mean if you want to open many game room at the same time it'll cost you a lot of hardware.

Run as headless mode (No GUI) will help you a bit but that's not enough (Currently I've done that on DO).

So my recommendation is don't use UNET if you want massive users on your game.